# How to display data from mysql with id sent with javascript ( Adobe Phonegap )

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, phonegap-desktop-app

I make a menu link with javascript. By using the parsing in php I display a menu with the help of javascript. The problem is how do I display data in accordance with the "id" which has been on the destination page.

Here's the code in index.html

```
function loadkategori(idnya){
        $('#contentID').load('kategori.php?id='+idnya, function(){
            $('#myListview').listview().listview('refresh');
        });
    }   

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/fiqi/fiqi2/kuliner/www/parsing2.php',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data, status){
                $.each(data, function(i,item){
                // $("#listview").append("<li><a href=#><img src="+item.lokasigambar+"><h2>"+item.namatempatnya+"</a><p>Kalimat</p></h2></li>");

                // seharusnya menggunakan class, tidak inline function
                $('#listview').append('<li data-filtertext="form checkboxradio widget checkbox input checkboxes controlgroups" onclick="loadkategori('+item.idkat+')"><a href="" data-ajax="false">'+item.namakategori+'</a></li>');
            });
            // $("#listview");
            // $('ul').listview('refresh');
            $('#listview').listview().listview('refresh');
            // $('#element').collapsibleset('refresh');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error terjadi');
            }
        });
    });
```

here's the code in kategori.php
[image: kategori.php]

The code in kategori.php doesn't work on adobe phonegap.

Comment: Paste the code for kategori.php instead of a screenshot, so it's readable and searchable and won't rot. But first, figure out [which part of the code is actually having problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now it's hard to tell if your problem is with Phonegap, PHP errors, your logic, or what.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't implement you code but as far as i understand, You need to use some http request function to get data from serverside php rather than using load(), go for using $.get(). That might work out as a solution to your problem.

function loadkategori(idnya){

```
    var data = $.get('kategori.php?id='+idnya, function(data,status){
       //PROCESS YOUR DATA OR CALL YOUR FUNCTION TO POPULATE YOUR LISTVIEW
        });
    }
```

Secondly you should use either xml or json data for client server communication. That would make your program simple and more efficient. You might paste your php code instead of putting screenshot so that some editing or testing can be done.